# How to get specific ListView item position to TextView without clicking it

Tags: android, listview, textview, leaderboard

I'm trying to make a Leaderboard with Listview

I have a Listview where the position of items is always change everytime the Score is change.

I already get the Username and the Score to show into the textview using SharedPref after user press the button, but the position of items is auto generated with Baseadapter.

I have no idea how to get the position without click it's Listview item, i mean when leaderboardActivity is open it will automatically show up the user Position, Username, and Score to the textview.

*sorry my english is not good

Comment: Post your codes so that we can understand your problem well

Comment: Provide the codes what you have done